# repeat each loop every 1 second

Tags: jquery

For the below code, how do i repeat the each loop every 1 second on hover?  So when the mouse is over `prevbutton` the each loop runs every 1 second?

```
$('.prevbutton').hover(function() {
    container.animate({'scrollLeft': '-'+scroll}, 5000);

    $('.parent-container').each(function() {


    });

}, function(){
    container.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.prevbutton').hover(function() {
      container.animate({'scrollLeft': '-'+scroll}, 5000);
      var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
           $('.parent-container').each(function() {

           });
      }, 1000);
      $(this).data('intervalId', intervalId);    
}, function(){
    container.stop();
    clearInterval($(this).data('intervalId'));
});
```